# Prepare for Cell.Value throwing Type Mismatch for "#VALUE!" in Visual Basic Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm implementing an Excel macro in Visual Basic that colors all cells in a sheet according to some rules based on how its value compares some other cells.

During this I try to check each cell's value like this:

```
Set ActualCell = Cells(RowIndex, 2)

With ActualCell
  If ForceRequiredFormatting And .Value = "" And .Interior.Color <> 255 Then
    .... something
```

The problem is that .Value throws Type Mismatch (13) even when I try to read the value (notice I'm not setting anything yet), if I type `#VALUE!` in the cell.

Why is this? How can I prepare for this? should I handle the error with try-catch? Am I able to check some conditions on `ActualCell` to see if the .Value can be read without throwing an error?

I could check for `.Text == "#VALUE!"` maybe, but I'm worried that this is only one type of cell value that cannot be read. I'm not an expert on what other errors can excel communicate through these values in cells.

Comment: I think you should first of all check if the cell contains an error or not. Check Function [IsError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function). Expresions like `#VALUE!` or `#NA!" ` are, actually, errors, and should be treated like that, not like other strings. Also, what is `ForceRequiredFormatting`? Is it an UDF? Can you post the code?

Comment: from @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns comment, you can try: `CStr(.Value) = "a"`

Comment: Could you not use conditional formatting instead?